# Instantiate variable and compile sass/less file on request

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, sass, less

i wonder if using nodejs or another server side language is there a way to basically receive a request for example

http://doman.com/getCSS/?type=4

and then replace the value of a variable with the url param in a sass/less file then compile into a css file and retrieve that as a response to the request.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Node.js you can basically do something like this, make sure you have the `express` and `less` NPM packages installed:

```
var express = require('express');
var less = require('less');
var app = express();

app.get('/getCSS/:id', function(req, res){
  less.render('.class { width: ' + req.params.id  + 'px; }', function (e, css) {
    res.send(css);
  });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

This is a quick 'n dirty script (no error checking or input validation whatsoever) that will accept requests to `http://localhost:3000/getCSS/:id` and output the given `id` as some variable in your LESS code.

```
# curl http://localhost:3000/getCSS/4
.class {
  width: 4px;
}
```

Of course you are free to use the parameters any way you like by inserting them into your LESS templates.